# Folders installed by Python Markdown

Tags: python, markdown

When I installed Python Markdown, I noticed that it added files to a `build/docs/extensions` folder. Where can I find this folder? I've searched through my machine, but came up empty.

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of the build process, Python-Markdown also builds the docs (from Markdown text files into HTML files). However, as the generated files are written to the build directory, they are deleted in the cleanup step after install (the build dir is deleted). The docs are hosted [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/index.html), but if you would like a local copy, you can build them  yourself.

First you need a copy if the source files either from [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) or [GitHub](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown). then from within the top directory, run the following command:

```
python setup.py build_docs
```

The docs will be written to `build/docs`. As we didn't complete the install process, the files haven't been deleted yet.

The complete steps to download and build might look this (on Linux using the current release of Python-Markdown):

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/Markdown/Markdown-2.5.2.tar.gz
tar xvzf Markdown-2.5.2.tar.gz
cd markdown-2.5.2/
python setup.py build_docs
cd build/docs
```

From that point you can move/copy the files to wherever you would like them, or open them in your browser of choice to view them.

Comment: Weird that they get built then deleted. Thanks!

Comment: Well, they get written to the build dir. The last step in the 'install' command is to clean up the temporary build dir. As long as we can run 'build' seperately, we can avoid the cleanup when we need the docs. We would need to inject a step into the install process to copy the built docs somewhere. But where? Even among different Linux distros, the proper location would be different. And AFAICT, distutils doesn't know anything about a docs location. It just so happens that the docs building script was implemented as parts of the build script. It doesn't have to be and may not always be.